# ExpressJS 4 in OpenShift Issue

Tags: node.js, express, openshift

Whenever I try to update express to 4.2.0 in openshift I get the 503 error. Any idea on how to resolve this? All I did was create a NodeJS application add MongoDB cartridge and using ssh, update the package.json to set express to 4.2.0 and ran npm install. After restarting the application I get a 503 on the web page. Does openshift support ExpressJS version 4?

Comment: Its likely that the application wasn't restarted properly when you did the manual update. Try restarting the app and see if that brings it back up.

Comment: @Ehci, possible that your code has not been ported from 3.x to 4.x

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same issue. Using express 4.9.8, I can run locally just fine but when trying to run after deployment on OpenShift I get the following:

```
==> app-root/logs/nodejs.log-20150224074926 <==
};
mixin(app, proto);
mixin(app, EventEmitter.prototype);
app.request = { __proto__: req, app: app };
app.response = { __proto__: res, app: app };
app.init();
return app;
} has no method 'createServer'
    at self.initializeServer (/var/lib/openshift/54e8fbd85973ca16e40000d6/app-root/runtime/repo/server.js:116:28)
    at self.initialize (/var/lib/openshift/54e8fbd85973ca16e40000d6/app-root/runtime/repo/server.js:134:14)

==> app-root/logs/nodejs.log-20150224095524 <==
    app.handle(req, res, next);
};
mixin(app, proto);
mixin(app, EventEmitter.prototype);
app.request = { __proto__: req, app: app };
app.response = { __proto__: res, app: app };
app.init();
return app;
} has no method 'createServer'
at self.initializeServer (/var/lib/openshift/54e8fbd85973ca16e40000d6/app-root/runtime/repo/server.js:116:28)
```

I get the impression that OpenShift does not support the newer versions of Express.

Comment: I was actually able to get this working and it was an issue in my code. I still get this error when I tail the log but it was nothing apparently.

Answer (score 0):

I started my app in Express3 using the OpenShift default code, pushed to OpenShift (happy, happy), and then locally decided that I'd better re-tool to Express4 and ran into the same problem.  Lot of head-bangin' on my desk.

Don't know if there's a way to do it and keep it but I couldn't get the /bin/www approach to work.  Had to move all that code back to /server.js, retire /bin/www, edit the scripts.start and main variables in package.json and was eventually successful.

```
package.json exerpt:
...
  "scripts": {
  "start": "node server.js"  // Was "npm start"
},
"main": "server.js"
```

So then the remote push/build worked.  The local one starts up with "npm start" as expected.

Comment: I didn't change anything expect ip and port (obviously) and my app didn't started before adding "main" in package.json. So "main" is important here, if evrything is fine.